# Combine multiple regular expressions in to one

Tags: regex

given the following sample strings, how can the highlighted parts be extracted using regex?

- x => x.`One.Two[0].Three.get_Item(0).Four[0].Five`
- x => x.`One.Two[0].Three.get_Item(0).Four[0].Five.get_Item(0)`
- x => x.`One.Two[0].Three.get_Item(0).Four[0].Five[0]`
- x => Convert(x.`One.Two[0].Three.get_Item(0).Four[0].Five`)
- x => Convert(x.`One.Two[0].Three.get_Item(0).Four[0].Five.get_Item(0)`)
- x => Convert(x.`One.Two[0].Three.get_Item(0).Four[0].Five[0]`)
- x => Convert(x.`One.Two[0].Three.get_Item(0).Four[0].Five`, Object)
- x => Convert(x.`One.Two[0].Three.get_Item(0).Four[0].Five.get_Item(0)`, Object)
- x => Convert(x.`One.Two[0].Three.get_Item(0).Four[0].Five[0]`, Object)

so far, i was able to come up with a couple of different regex patterns but ideally i'd like to have a single regex that will handle all the above cases.

this is what i have so far:

`\.(.+)(?<!\d)\)$`  and `\.(.+), Object\)` and `\.(.+)`

here's the sample data to play with: https://regex101.com/r/jxqsQl/2

appreciate any help you can provide...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regex will do what you want. It looks for multiple groups of a `.` and a word, followed optionally by digits enclosed in `[]` or `()`:

```
(?:\.\w+(?:[[(]\d+[)\]])?)+
```

[Demo on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/ZZC7Xa/3)

Comment: one small detail... how to skip the first dot? currently the match is: `.One.Two....` i'd like the leading dot omitted. so the match would be `One.Two....`. thanks!

Comment: @RyanGunner it might be easier to just trim it (as it will always be just a single `.`), otherwise you have to put a special group at the beginning e.g. https://regex101.com/r/I5iiZ7/2

Comment: yeah you're right. that complicates it quite a bit it seems. i'll use a trim in my app. thanks again for the updated pattern.

Comment: @RyanGunner no worries.